# Landingpage missing in Sitemap.xml in Shopware 6

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

I have recently created a Landingpage and it does not appear to be listed in the sitemap. Refreshing indexes and generating sitemaps manually did not do the trick.

Does anyone have an Idea how to fix this or where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging I suggest to the mode "live". The sitemaps are generated when requesting `/sitemap.xml`. Now you can set a breakpoint in

`vendor/shopware/core/Content/Sitemap/Service/SitemapExporter.php:47`

In my case I could reproduce your issue.

There is a loop over URL providers:

```
foreach ($this->urlProvider as $urlProvider) {
```

You see the `HomeUrlProvider` is called and then
`\Shopware\Core\Content\Sitemap\Provider\CategoryUrlProvider`.

The `\Shopware\Core\Content\Sitemap\Provider\CategoryUrlProvider::getUrls` only fetches real categories. Even landing pages are listed under categories in the admin panel, they are stored in the `landing_page_*` tables and so are not covered by this URL provider.

There seems no `UrlProvider` specifically for Landingpages (as of 6.5.3.3 where I checked).

So this might be intended that landing pages are not listed in the Sitemap?

[image: Classes extending the AbstratUrlProvider]

You could - as a workaround - add custom URLs via `config/packages/z-shopware.yaml`

```
shopware:
    sitemap:
        custom_urls:
            - url: 'my-landing-page'
              lastMod: '2023-10-07 21:59:43'
              changeFreq: weekly
              salesChannelId: 7a0794721cba448d87e0a7c752ffedff
```

Drawback is that you have to specify the lastMod date manually.